# Ajax load causes content to jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-events

When I am loading in content from another page using `Ajax` my footer jumps up to below my header before moving back down.

I recon this is caused by `$('#container').remove();` which means I am essentially removing the container before loading in the new container.

Is there a way to stop my footer from jumping up and down between `Ajax` loads?

Here is my JQuery

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = this.href;
   $('nav a.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
   $(this).addClass('highlight');
   $('#container').remove();
   $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn(3500);
});
```

I'v uploaded an example of what is happening to me on a test server [here](https://ajax-jump.000webhostapp.com/). 
 I had to upload it as a snippet or pen does not allow more than one HTML page

Comment: Couldn't you just use `$('#container').load(...)` to replace the content of the container directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not remove `#container`

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = this.href;

  $('nav a.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
  $(this).addClass('highlight');

  //$('#container').remove();
  $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn(3500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfect but i think this can help you to get an idea. You can set min-height of **#content** or you can add a **class** **.stick_footer** to **footer** immediately  after removing container and remove **class** **.stick_footer** after data loaded.
sorry for bad english.

```
.stick_footer{
  position:absolute; bottom:0;left:0;right:0; top:9em;
}
```